# Intellisense in NodeJS for jsonix

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, jsonix

Newbie to Node.js - and maybe this is a dumb question. I'm a C# developer . I am generating javascript schema from xsd files - then I want to create xml files from that using jsonix.

Question: Can I somehow get intellisense for the object generated so I can fill out the details easily? I'm using visual studio but we have webstorm etc.

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Author of Jsonix here.

As far as I know there's no possibility for Intellisense (or likes) at the moment.

What people typically do is unmarshal a more-or-less complete XML example and use it as basis.